# DISTINCT clause doesn't work with odbc_exec on linux

Tags: linux, ms-access, odbc, mdbtools

I'm trying to read rows from a .mdb file (MS Access) on Linux (Ubuntu), I've installed php5-odbc, mootools etc... My code is:

```
$dbName = "/path/file.mdb";

$handle=odbc_connect ("DRIVER=MDBTools; DBQ=$dbName;", "", "");

if(!$handle) {
   print "<p>Uh-oh! Failure to connect to DSN: <br />";
   odbc_errormsg();
}
else {
   print "done";
   $resultset=odbc_exec ($handle, "SELECT DISTINCT(col) FROM tab");
   odbc_result_all($resultset, "border=2");
   odbc_close($handle);
}
```

if I change SQL clause to `SELECT col FROM tab` it works well... Instead with DISTINCT clause I have this error:

```
odbc_exec(): SQL error: [unixODBC]Couldn't parse SQL, SQL state 08001 in SQLExecDirect
```

I've tried with square brackets and without too but it's the same... Help!!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col FROM tab
```

Comment: What is the error message? Please post the exact SQL you are using.

Comment: Sql: SELECT DISTINCT X_TZART FROM particolarita, error: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [unixODBC]Couldn't parse SQL, SQL state 08001 in SQLExecDirect

Comment: Can you try this with another column, which has no underscore in it's name? - I vaguely rember there were issues with mdbtools and underscores, but I cannot recall details or a solution.